# Wicket basic implementation of wizard steps

Tags: java, wicket, wizard, multi-step

is there any basic implementation wicket 6.20 provides for a step overview functionality like in [this picture](http://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/2111.jpg) or [like this if the other won't work](https://www.google.ch/search?q=wizard%20multi%20step&rls=com.microsoft:de-CH:IE-Address&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI5Oi7k5aeyAIVxT8aCh1sJAOO&biw=2438&bih=1253)?
When looking at the documentation I couldn't find anything close to it, so I started by doing my own implementation like

```
public List<String> getSteps(WizardModel model){
    Iterator<IWizardStep> iterator = model.stepIterator();
    List<String> steps = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 1; iterator.hasNext(); i++){
        steps.add(String.valueOf(i));
        iterator.next();
    }

    //model.getActiveStep(); unnecessary in this context
    return steps;
}
```

to get all possible steps in a List. And now I would go on by getting the index of the current panel (if possible) and get it's state by `isColmplete();` to mark it in a different color. But I can't believe, that I'm the first one with this problem.
Should I go on with my idea or is there a better option?

Comment: Link with image requires login

Comment: Strange, I've never been on the site before and don't need a login, however [this one is google pictures](https://www.google.ch/search?q=wizard+multi+step&rls=com.microsoft:de-CH:IE-Address&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI5Oi7k5aeyAIVxT8aCh1sJAOO&biw=2438&bih=1253)

Comment: Google show few hundreds of images. Did you check wicket Breadcrumb? Has estetical appearance like these images (but nothing to wizard functionality)

Comment: Self-correction wicket breadcrumb is not in main code, but additional by same authors (https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/breadcrumb)

Comment: Never heard of it, but I'll check it out :-) The pictures are just to give you some idea what I mean

Comment: It seems like this is not really what I'm looking for. I'm trying to get an overview like: These are the numbers of steps, you are at this step and you have already completed those. But thank you for the input anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (have to) implement a wizard yourself, it is not too hard.

I would use a `AjaxTabbedPanel` as basis. You just have to add a 'next', 'back' and 'finish' bar below, and do some `CSS` styling

Comment: I guessed something like this would happen, I'll wait a moment for other opinions, else I'm going to mark your answear as accepted.

Comment: If you create a Wizard component that has this (very useful!) functionality, it would be awesome if you put it on github as standalone project, so others might benefit (and participate/help you) :)

Comment: You might want to look at wicket bootstrap wizard functionally.

Comment: Sometimes concept of "Wizard' is near to 'Tabbed pane'. I made such exchange on SWT/Jface platform because of small API truobles