# Control Wicket wizard's flow by setting setComplete(boolean)

Tags: wicket, conditional-statements, wizard

Hey there I'm still trying to improve a customized Wicket Wizard to display the steps with following states: active, completed, pending. Therefore the information of `isCompleted();` should return the right value. Refering to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909817/wicket-wizard-gives-false-information-in-method-iscomplete), `isComplete();` returns true, if the wizard can go to the next step.
How can I manipulate this information to get the full advantage of my draft? E.g. in one WizardStep I have multiple input fields.

```
super(new ResourceModel("daten.title"), new ResourceModel("daten.summary"));
java.util.Collections.addAll(sprachen, "Deutsch","English","Français","Italiano");

add(name = new RequiredTextField<String>("name", Model.of("")));
add(vorname = new RequiredTextField<String>("vorname",  Model.of("")));
add(strasse = new RequiredTextField<String>("strasse",  Model.of("")));
add(ort = new RequiredTextField<String>("ort",  Model.of("")));
...
```

I don't want the step to "be completed" until each field is filled out. To check the condition I'd have to add an `AjaxListener` to each component and check for it's state to `setComplete(boolean);`. 
 Can I control this flow from outside the wizard form? For example with an implementation of `ICondition` or is there another way? Because basically I can't go to the next step, because all of my textfields are **`RequiredTextField`** and cannot be skipped.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

***Update / Solution***

```
Component buttonbar = getForm().get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID);
buttonbar.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Just `get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID);` won't work.
Thanks to Sven Meier for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior to all your form components.

Then override #onEvent() in your wizard:

```
public MyWizard(id, WizardModel model) {
    super(id, model);

    get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID).setOutputMarkupId(true);
}

public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
    if (event.getPayload() instanceof AjaxRequestTarget) {
         ((AjaxRequestTarget)event.getPayload()).add(get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID));
    }
}
```

Let your step#isComplete() return true depending on its model values, this way the wizard buttons will always be up to date.

Comment: Still checking your suggestion, but `get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID).setOutputMarkupId(true);` throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: This line `((AjaxRequestTarget)event.getPayload()).add(get(Wizard.BUTTONS_ID));` throws the null pointer as well, but else it seems working, how can I avoid the null poiner?